# Image Comparison Fast GPU Algorithm find miss match

Tags: algorithm, opencl, rgb, h.264, yuv

I would like to know what is the best way for comparing 2 RGB images. 
I would like to either find a list of bounding boxes for the difference. 
Or a unified bounding box for all changes. Either is ok.

So say I am comparing 2 desktop screens and one of the images has the time different in lower right corner as well as an icon has moved on the upper left corner of the screen

The algorithm can find the bounding boxes of the the icon that moved and the number (second) that changes which gives me 2 boxes which contain the changes Or it can generate a MIN/MAX sort of logic and generate a single box including a union of those 2 changes. In this case the box would be the size of whole screen as my example is for a worst case scenario.  (I know that one can union the boxes and get a single unioned box). But maybe there is a faster algorithm then finding each box separate. That is why an algorithm which find a union is also ok.

I have compared by pixel by pixel and found the min max for the whole screen where the changes exist in a nested loop like fashion.
I even have tried this on OPENCL but the speed for a 4K images is not acceptable as it is 0^2.

Is there a search like algorithm that could speed this search of the screen. 
Maybe represent it as a graph. Sort of like A* or some other heuristic  based search?

Maybe scaling it down and doing the search followed by a second search only on the section that detected a change ?

Maybe converting to YUV help?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution I can think of. Convert the image to greyscale, perform an xor on the two images, then use a clustering algorithm to find bounding boxes.